# If $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is a group morphism, then $x\mapsto x^2$ is a group morphism

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

> Prove that, $$f:(G,·)\longrightarrow(G,·) \text{ with }f(x)=x^{-1} \text{, morphism } \implies g:(G,·)\longrightarrow(G,·) \hspace{5mm}\text{ with }g(x)=x^2 \text{, morphism}$$
> Where morphism means a morphism between groups.

To prove this statement I have to show that $g(xy)=g(x)g(y)$, i.e. $$xyxy=x^2y^2$$ using the fact that $x^{-1}y^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$ (since $\varphi^{-1}$ is a morphism).

My attempt, $$xyxy=x^{2}y^{2}\iff f(xyxy)=f(x^2y^2)\iff y^{-1}x^{-1}y^{-1}x^{-1}=y^{-2}x^{-2}\iff x^{-1}y^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}\hspace{2mm}\blacksquare$$
Is my proof correct?

*I have to point out that this question has already been answered [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/901338/abelian-group-and-morphism-equivalent-statement), although it didn't work on the implication (ii) $\implies$ (iii) which is the one I'm working on. So please, don't close this one.*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should not write $\phi^{-1}$ and $\phi^2$, because this is misleading. Better use different names. If you know that $x^{-1}y^{-1}=y^{-1}x^{-1}$, then $xy=yx$, so that $(xy)^2=x^2y^2$ - done.

Comment: True, because they don't have any relation between each other! Thanks for the help, although I didn't want to use the property of G being abelian to proof the statement since then I would just be copying the answer given in the other post in which it uses $(ii)\implies (i)\implies (iii)$ to proof that $(ii)\implies(iii)$.

Comment: Still, this is "probably the easiest way", see the answer below (which got several upvotes for it). And indeed, saying that $f(x)=x^{-1}$ is a morphism is really saying immediately that $xy=yx$, after just inverting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest way to see this is to prove that if $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an automorphism (note it is clearly its own inverse), then $G$ is abelian. This is easy to see since $\phi((xy)^{-1})=yx$ while $\phi(x^{-1})\phi(y^{-1})=xy$, so we have that $xy=yx$. That is if $x\mapsto x^{-1}$ is an automorphism, then $G$ is abelian. From this it is clear that $\psi(xy)=(xy)^2=x^2y^2=\psi(x)\psi(y)$ is a homomorphism.

Answer (score 0):

Your bidirectional implications are fine - the only thing to plug is to mention that $f$ is a bijection (regardless of whether or not it is a group homomorphism), therefore the first bidirectional implication holds, specifically $f(xyxy) = f(x^2y^2) \implies xyxy = x^2y^2$ requires injectivity of $f$.

So your proof is mostly fine, but a bit convoluted. Note that $g(xy)=g(x)g(y)$ is equivalent to $xyxy=x^2y^2$, which is equivalent to $xy=yx$ by multiplying on the left by $x^{-1}$ and on the right by $y^{-1}$. So $g$ being a homomorphism is equivalent to every pair of elements of $G$ commuting.

The same trick can be used to show that $f$ being a homomorphism is equivalent to $G$ being abelian.

You can turn these into a cycle of implications as in your linked question, but I don't think much is really gained by doing so in lieu of proving both equivalences with $G$ being abelian.